# Safari: This webpage is using significant memory

Tags: memory, safari

When I run my project in safari from time to time it shows a warning about significant memory usage. When I open Timelines in dev tools I see this:
[image]

Don't completely understand what related to the 'Page' category and how can I improve this.

Would be really grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

According to this [article](https://www.macworld.com/article/3148256/it-s-time-for-safari-to-go-on-a-memory-diet.html#:%7E:text=The%20app%20itself%20is%20using,it%20uses%20in%20Activity%20Monitor.), Safari uses a minimum of 1 Gb RAM and each opened tab also uses extra RAM on top of it. The ram usage increases an awful lot the longer a tab is kept opened and operates. Because each tab loads respective content, more memory is consumed. Each opened tab will be similar to a sandbox version of Safari.

This [article](https://daringfireball.net/2010/11/flash_free_and_cheating_with_google_chrome), however, shows ways to reduce memory usage by Safari. **The article is written 10 years ago** and in this day and age, the Flashplayer is less of an issue. Recommended steps are to disable **Flash Player** and any old ClickToFlash plugins within Safari.

As a side note, Safari 13 and onward versions are RAM friendly and hags less memory than its previous predecessors. However, the issue with multiple opened tabs is still a problem.

A number of solutions that may apply to you:

- Reduce the number of installed extensions
- Keep fewer tabs open
- Clear history every so often (once per 2 months or less)

Comment: thanks a lot! very useful information! will read those articles now

Comment: @Carolina You're welcome! The issue with Safari is as described. I would also suggest you to change web browser if possible. There are better alternatives to it. Opera is said to consume less memory.